# Possible to backup an android by just copying all the files?

Tags: backup

Is it possible to backup an android by just copying all the files onto a PC? Is it really necessary to use a backup program?

I just dragged and dropped all the files from my android internal storage, and they appear to be all there. The question is whether they can actually be used if I need to restore something.

Seems like everywhere I look there are programs to archive everything into one backup file, and then save the backup file on a cloud or you copy it to your PC. Is this really necessary? Is it possible to get by just copying all the files?

Comment: Same question here: [Backup Possibility?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/51011/16575). Same answer: Backup – yes. Restore: Probably not. Or at maximum partially. Or with such a huge overhead, that it isn't worth it. For better ways, see [Full Backup of non-rooted devices](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/28296/16575).